# cURL authentication not working

Tags: php, curl

I'm new to cURL and php and not really sure what's wrong. I need to check what username and password is being returned from server and not what user enters to authenticate the display of the array. Could anybody help me please? This is my code:

```
<?php
class Application_Model_abc extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{
          private $pwd= "un:pswd";
              public function def()
              {
                $curl = curl_init();
                $url ="https://someurl.com";
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD,$this->pwd);
                $data = curl_exec($curl);
                print_r(curl_getinfo($curl));
                curl_close($curl);
                $arr= json_decode($data,true);  
                print_r($arr);

    }
}
?>
```

Comment: try with square brackets  `$pwd= "[un]:[pswd]";`

Comment: I did but to no avail. What I need to do is check what the server is returning as username and password.

Comment: what do you mean "returning", you have to supply the username and password to gain access to the password protected site/directory. You can test this by password protecting a directory you control with .htaccess http://davidwalsh.name/password-protect-directory-using-htaccess

Comment: I'm sorry I wasn't clear enough earlier. So, here's how it is. I have an API (the url) and to get to it, the user needs to enter the username and password. Now, the credentials are temporary as it might expire. So, I need to check which username and password is being returned by the server after the user types it in so that if the api doesn't get displayed even after the user types in the correct one, I would know that there is some problem with the credentials in the server, that it might have expired or something.

Comment: So you really need the authentication method to log incorrect and expired attempts to access the url? How are you protecting the url (api)? login form, check get parameters, protected directory with prompt, protected directory with username and password in url (like FTP)?

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot. I was able to solve it. I just had to make the error already present in the API and display it...